# Vuejs display Laravel errors in flash component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

In controller I have a method, where I validate request. I have and custom error, see please code:

```
public function createComment(Request $request) {
   $request->validate(['body' => 'string|min:10', 'type' => 'integer']);

   if($this->lastComment(Auth::user()->id)) {
      return response()->json(['errors' => 'Please try after 24 hours..'], 422);
   } else {
      $comment = Comment::create($request->all());
      return $comment;
   }
}
```

In vue I have axios:

```
   axios.post('/createReview', {
                    body: this.body,
                    user_id: this.user_id,
                    type: this.type,
                }).then(response => {
                    this.$emit('created', response.data);

                }).catch(error => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    this.flash(error.response.data, 'error');
                });
```

How I can correctly send these errors on component flash? When I get error on component I get `[Object object]`. I use this flash package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-flash-message

Answer (score 0):

That  component will only render one message at a time and you are passing it an object.

```
this.flash(error.response.data.errors, 'error');
```

Comment: In errors can be message, but can be `errors.body`, `errors.type` where messages of validation

Comment: You can concat them into a string e.g. error.response.body.join(', ') or loop them. In a form I would not do it this way. I would render the errors under each field.